# Android Studio: Unresolved reference despite Gradle sync successful after adding third party implementation. Works fine with previous version

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to add this library:

https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator

I have added this to my build.gradle file's dependencies:

`implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski:viewpropertyobjectanimator:1.5.0'`

The Gradle sync is successful after this too.

However when I try to use it:

`ViewPropertyObjectAnimator.animate(this@CustomToolbar).topMargin(it).setDuration(200).start()`

It keeps telling me `Unresolved reference: ViewPropertyObjectAnimator`. And I am unable to import as the `com.bartoszlipinski` doesn't exist when importing.

If I change the library version from 1.5.0 to 1.4.5:

`implementation 'com.bartoszlipinski:viewpropertyobjectanimator:1.4.5'`

it works fine and import works fine too.

I would prefer using the newer version instead of the old one. Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT:** I just noticed that even though Gradle sync is successful, it logs a warning:

`Failed to resolve: com.bartoszlipinski:viewpropertyobjectanimator:1.5.0 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app`

And with the older version, I can see the library in the Android Studio's "External Libraries" but it's not there in the newer library version:

[image]

**Edit 2:** I think I figured it out. I came across this:

https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator/issues/16

> Using custom bintray repo is a bit unusual, and mavenCentral only has up to 1.4.5. Any chance of updating to 1.5.0 on mavenCentral too? Just curious, but technically bintray works well for me atm too

So it seems like mavenCentral doesn't have the updated version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across this issue, I added jitpack repository to the `settings.gradle` file instead of the root file.

```
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Implementation in the build.gradle file was the same.

```
implementation 'com.github.blipinsk:ViewPropertyObjectAnimator:1.5.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. I came across this:

https://github.com/blipinsk/ViewPropertyObjectAnimator/issues/16

> Using custom bintray repo is a bit unusual, and mavenCentral only has up to 1.4.5. Any chance of updating to 1.5.0 on mavenCentral too? Just curious, but technically bintray works well for me atm too

So it seems like mavenCentral doesn't have the updated version. As a workaround, I added

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

to

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and then change the dependency to:

```
implementation 'com.github.blipinsk:ViewPropertyObjectAnimator:1.5.0'
```